# How to fix ResourceNumberLimitExceededException when creating Glue job in AWS?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-glue

I am trying to create an AWS Glue job and the creation fails with the following exception:

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"ResourceNumberLimitExceededException","requestId":"XXXX","errorMessage":"Failed to meet resource limits for operation","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

I have tried to reduce the dpu count, but the issue still persists.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you are allowed only 25 jobs. Please verify if you reached the limit. If you need to create more jobs, you have to raise a limit increase request to Aws.  Please see here for information on limits: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-service-limits.html

Comment: glad it was useful.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Was very useful