# AWS Glue Error ResourceNumberLimitExceededException when StartJobRun is called

Tags: aws-glue

Here is the error line

```
ERROR - Failed to run aws glue job, error: An error occurred (ResourceNumberLimitExceededException) when calling the StartJobRun operation: Reached the limit while starting jon run while starting a run for job with name: my_glue_job_test
```

The error occurs when StartJobRun is called and all I found about this error from docs is "A resource numerical limit was exceeded" which doesn't make any sense to me because last week it was working totally fine. I did not change anything and this error show up out of nowhere.

Also I think this is a different case from [How to fix ResourceNumberLimitExceededException when creating Glue job in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52275952/11036620) since I tried to create a new job and create_job is working totally fine. However, when StartJobRun is called the exact same error show up.

Does anyone know how is this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the similar issue today, Just go to aws service quota and change all the quotas that got changed to 0 to its default value. It worked for me!   This issue is caused by aws internally.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same error and we were able to run the ETL´s by changing the quotas. However, whenever we try to start a notebook session to develop an ETL it doesn´t assign a server and shows the same errors. I think it´s an error form AWS.