# Getting an error in AWS Glue -> Jobs(New) Failed to update job [gluestudio-service.us-east-2.amazonaws.com] updateDag: InternalFailure: null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I've been using AWS Glue studio for Job creation. Till now I was using Job Legacy but recently Amazon has migrated to the new version `Glue Job v_3.0` Where I am trying to create a job using Spark script editor.

**Steps to be followed**

1. Open ***Region-Code*/console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home?region=*Region-Code*#/v2/home**
2. Click Create Job link
3. Select Spark script editor
4. Make sure you selected the Create a new script with boilerplate code
5. Then click the Create button in the top right corner.

When I try to save the Job after fill all the required information, I'm getting an error like below

```
Failed to update job
[gluestudio-service.us-east-1.amazonaws.com] createJob: InternalServiceException: Failed to meet resource limits for operation
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note**

- I've tried the Legacy Job creation as well where I was getting an error like below

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"ResourceNumberLimitExceededException","requestId":"179c2de8-6920-4adf-8791-ece7cbbfbc63","errorMessage":"Failed to meet resource limits for operation","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

- **Is this something related to Internal configuration issue?**
- **As I was using client's provided account I don't have permission to see the Limitations and all**

Answer (score 0):

Based on the steps you have mentioned, you are doing it right. There are two things to consider:

1. By default you are only allowed 25 jobs - check with the client and see if they have a limit in the number of jobs that can be created.
2. Check the IAM role you are assuming - maybe a different IAM role will have less limitations and you can assume a different role.

See this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-service-limits.html

And this question has been answered before here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275952/how-to-fix-resourcenumberlimitexceededexception-when-creating-glue-job-in-aws)